# How to keep a baby cool in summer without air conditioning?

Tags: infant, development

I have concerns regarding our baby (less than 1 yr) sleeping in an air conditioned room. I live in Mumbai. Its an area with extremely high humidity and very hot temperatures. We all sleep in an air conditioned room. But we are afraid that the baby will be accustomed to sleeping in A.C. rooms only, and that this might interfere with her sleeping in areas that aren't air conditioned.

If we go out to some relative's place, will she be able to sleep in a non A.C. room?
Is there any way to keep the baby cool without A.C.?

Comment: A table fan. Don't point it directly at the baby, but close enough so that the air around her is circulated. Also, keep the baby hydrated with frequent feedings.

Comment: Just as an anecdote: We had a spell of unusually warm (for Germany) weather when our child was a few weeks old, with temperatures in excess of 35°C in our room. Our child coped just fine, but drank a lot. Make sure you offer enough fluids, dehydration is very dangerous. Also, no blanket - at these temperatures diapers are sufficient clothing.

Answer (score 5):

I don't have direct experience with a child becoming so accustomed to sleeping with air conditioning that they were unable to sleep without it, but I know adults who have that problem, so I think it is a very real concern for you.

My suggestion is that during the two weeks leading up to your visits to your relatives without A.C., you gradually lower the amount of A.C. you use in your house (or at least the baby's room).  The goal is to have the temperature as high as is safe for a day or two before the trip, with the gradual increase helping ease your child through the transition.  That doesn't mean that you won't face some sleepless nights while visiting your relatives, but at least it gives you a better chance of your daughter falling asleep.

However, be very careful about making sure she does not overheat, either while you are gradually increasing the temperature at your home, or while visiting your relatives.  Overheating is very dangerous to an infant.

Make sure you don't swaddle her when you have the temperature raised.

Check for [warning signs](http://www.achildbirth.com/Overheating-the-Baby.shtml) frequently:

- Red pimples on the cheeks, neck, forehead, head, arms, or legs
- Excessive sweating
- Wet hair (from sweat)
- Rapid breathing
- Flushed, red skin
- General restlessness

Some suggestions to [help keep your baby comfortable](http://www.parents.com/baby/care/newborn/making-baby-comfortable-in-summer-heat/) while sleeping without air conditioning:

- Pick the Right Clothes

> If you're going to be indoors, dress your infant in loose-fitting, lightweight garments, preferably made from a natural fiber like cotton, which absorbs perspiration better than synthetic fabrics. A good rule of thumb: "Dress the baby the way you're dressed," Dr. Epstein says. "If you're wearing shorts and a T-shirt, that will be fine for her too."

- Provide Good Ventilation

> Since a baby doesn't perspire effectively, he can become overheated
>   far more quickly than an adult. That's why you should never leave an
>   infant in a hot room or a parked car. Even a few minutes could cause
>   his temperature to spike and, in extreme cases, may prove
>   life-threatening.

- Keep Him Hydrated

> Even if you don't see beads of sweat dripping from your infant's
>   forehead, he can be losing precious fluids to perspiration in hot
>   weather. A flushed face, skin that's warm to the touch, rapid
>   breathing, and restlessness may be warning signs of dehydration. Since
>   infants under 6 months shouldn't drink water (babies over 6 months can
>   take in modest amounts), replace the lost liquids by giving him extra
>   formula or by nursing more frequently. Babies should drink at least 50
>   percent more than usual in the summer (normal fluid intake is at least
>   two ounces per pound per day), so a ten-pound baby who usually takes
>   in 20 ounces should be offered a minimum of 30 ounces.

Comment: Good list. However, it should be pointed out that sweating alone is not really a warning sign, but simply a sign that the child is warm. I made a small edit.